# Forming where clause on Timestamp column in Oracle, The data is in java.util.Date format

Tags: java, oracle, date, timestamp

I am having a timestamp column name DOWNLOAD_DATE in one database table named DOWNLOAD_TAB.

When I opened the Oracle SQL Developer the maximum date was "24.02.12 13:48:39,286000000"

```
select TO_CHAR (MAX(DOWNLOAD_DATE)) from DOWNLOAD_TAB
```

But the Query above returned me the date as "24.02.12 13:48:39,286"

Now I want to form a Query that will give me all the records after a certain date, But I am having that date available in java.util.Date.

I can not use the preparedstatement of java due to some framework constraints. I need to use the Statement class.

Would anyone please suggest me a way to do this in java using java.sql.Statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely can't use prepared statements, this should work.  Format the date as you will, and then use TO_DATE in your sql statment using the same format.  Oracle has a default format, but I prefer explicitly stating the format.

```
Date now = new Date();
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(now);
String sqlVal = "TO_DATE('" + dateString + "', 'yyyyy-mm-dd')";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM DOWNLOAD_TAB WHERE download_date > " + sqlValue;
```

And that's why a prepared statement is always preferred.  As you can see, this code is ugly, error-prone, non-portable across databases, and open to sql injection attacks. And of course, prepared statement perform better.